# C# take a duplicate entry in a CSV file and remove the duplicate by taking an average

Tags: c#, list, csv

My program creates a .csv file with a persons name and an integer next to them.

Occasionally there are two entries of the same name in the file, but with a different time. I only want one instance of each person.

I would like to take the mean of the two numbers to produce just one row for the name, where the number will be the average of the two existing.

[image: This is my csv file]

So here Alex Pitt has two numbers. How can I take the mean of 105 and 71 (in this case) to produce a row that just includes Alex Pitt, 88?

Here is how I am creating my CSV file if reference is required.

```
public void CreateCsvFile()
    {
        PaceCalculator ListGather = new PaceCalculator();
        List<string> NList = ListGather.NameGain();
        List<int> PList = ListGather.PaceGain();

        List<string> nAndPList = NList.Zip(PList, (a, b) => a + ", " + b).ToList();

        string filepath = @"F:\A2 Computing\C# Programming Project\ScheduleFile.csv";

        using (var file = File.CreateText(filepath))
        {
            foreach (var arr in nAndPList)
            {
                if (arr == null || arr.Length == 0) continue;
                file.Write(arr[0]);
                for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    file.Write(arr[i]);
                }
                file.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As you are writing the CSV - you can write anything you like to it.  Just write the data you want.

Comment: I'm already doing that, I just want to be able to remove rows with duplicates.

Comment: What @Dan-o is trying to say is that you can remove the dupes *before* you write the CSV

Comment: so before I merge the two lists, I should remove or combine duplicates then?

Comment: @GeorgeBoulton - No, you have to merge (rather zip) the two lists first, but not as a string, then compute the average, then write out the records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, you can write your current `CreateCsvFile` much more simply like this:

```
public void CreateCsvFile()
{
    var filepath = @"F:\A2 Computing\C# Programming Project\ScheduleFile.csv";
    var ListGather = new PaceCalculator();

    var records =
        ListGather.NameGain()
            .Zip(ListGather.PaceGain(),
                (a, b) => String.Format("{0},{1}", a, b));

    File.WriteAllLines(filepath, records);
}
```

Now, it can easily be changed to work out the average pace if you have duplicate names, like this:

```
public void CreateCsvFile()
{
    var filepath = @"F:\A2 Computing\C# Programming Project\ScheduleFile.csv";
    var ListGather = new PaceCalculator();

    var records =
        from record in ListGather.NameGain()
            .Zip(ListGather.PaceGain(),
                (a, b) => new { Name = a, Pace = b })
        group record.Pace by record.Name into grs
        select String.Format("{0},{1}", grs.Key, grs.Average());

    File.WriteAllLines(filepath, records);
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. So here you're grouping the paces which finds the average?

Comment: @GeorgeBoulton - Not strictly speaking, the grouping just creates a list of values associated with each name. The call to `.Average()` reduces the list of integers down to a single double value by computing the average.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to merge the duplicates before you put everything into the CSV file.

use:

```
// The List with all duplicate values    
List<string> duplicateChecker = new List<string>();  

//Takes the duplicates and puts them in a new List. I'm using the NList because I assume the Names are the important part. 
duplicateChecker  = NList .Distinct().ToList();
```

Now you can simply Iterrate through the new list and search their values in your NList. Use a foreach loop which is looking up the index of the Name value in Nlist. After that you can use the Index to merge the integers with a simple math method.

```
//Something like this:
Make a foreach loop for every entry in your duplicateChecker => 

Use Distrinc again on duplicateChecker to make sure you won't go twice through the same duplicate =>

Get the Value of the current String and search it in Nlist =>

Get the Index of the current Element in Nlist and search for the Index in Plist =>

Get the Integer of Plist and store it in a array =>

// make sure your math method runs before a new name starts. After that store the new values in your nAndPList
Once the Loop is through with the first name use a math method.
```

I hope you understand what I was trying to say. However I would recommend using a unique identifier for your persons. Sooner or later 2 persons will appear with the same name (like in a huge company).

Answer (score -2):

Change the code below:

```
 List<string> nAndPList = NList.Zip(PList, (a, b) => a + ", " + b).ToList();
```

To

```
List<string> nAndPList = NList.Zip(PList, (a, b) => a + ", " + b)
                        .ToList()
                        .GroupBy(x => x.[The field you want to group by])
                        .Select(y => y.First);
```

Comment: nAndPList looks like Alexander, 22; John, 12; etc

Comment: Firstly I don't see John in the list you provided, secondly this is not incorrect...